# - Error -Function tried to send a message of type String

Tags: javascript, iot, node-red

I am publishing a random temperature with `topic:Test/Temperature`.

I want a chart that displays this temperature using the topic.

I am getting this error: `Function tried to send a message of type string`

[image: one]

[image: two]

[image: three]

I tried to remove the function or change the code inside the function, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: In future please do not post screen shots of code, they are normally hard to read, impossible for those users that need to use a screen reader and unsearchable. Please post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Answer (score 1):

Function nodes must **ALWAYS** return an object.

By returning just the `msg.topic` you have returned a string, which the error is correctly pointing out.

The correct version of the function would be:

```
msg.topic = 'Test/Temperature'
return msg
```

(But you can remove the whole function node and just set the `topic` and the `payload` in the inject node)

Comment: Very Helpful! I want the publisher and the subscriber to see the following values "temp" , "id" , "status"

But could the chart show only the temperature value?

example when publishing  {'id': '12345' , 'temperature' : '26' , 'status': 'off' }